# Adapter notify not working

Tags: java, android, listview, asynchronous, adapter

I load images asynchronously on my adapter.
But when setting the image (bitmap) nothing happens inside the listview.
Any ideas what's wrong?

Thanks in advance

This is my code that updates the object with an image ( in adapter) :

```
public void setImage(int position ,Bitmap bm){
    profielen.get(position).setThumbNail(bm);
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

Adapter :

```
public class LeaderBoardAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Profile>{

LayoutInflater vi;
List<Profile> profielen;
Context mContext;
int res;
public LeaderBoardAdapter(Context context, int resource,
        List<Profile> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.res = resource;
    this.profielen = objects;
    mContext = context;
    vi = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    ProfileHolder holder = null;
    if(convertView == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)mContext).getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(res, parent, false);

        holder = new ProfileHolder();
        holder.name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameChar);
        holder.pic = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageChar);
        holder.rank = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ratingNumber);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ProfileHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    Profile p = profielen.get(position);
    holder.name.setText(p.getName());
    holder.rank.setText(p.getRating());
    holder.pic.setImageBitmap(p.getThumbNail());

    return convertView;

}

public static class ProfileHolder{
    TextView name;
    ImageView pic;
    TextView rank;
}

public void setImage(int position ,Bitmap bm){
    profielen.get(position).setThumbNail(bm);
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

}

And get changed by this :

```
    imgurl =imgCharacter+imgurl;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = getImageLoader(); 
    imageLoader.get(imgurl, new ImageListener() {

                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }

                public void onResponse(ImageContainer response, boolean arg1) {
                    if (response.getBitmap() != null) {
                        lbadapter.setImage(pos, response.getBitmap());
                        lbadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    } 
                }
            });
```

Imageloader (Volley)

```
       imageLoader = new ImageLoader(queue, new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
        private final LruCache<String, Bitmap> cache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>           (20);


        @Override
        public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
            return cache.get(url);
        }

        @Override
        public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
            cache.put(url, bitmap);
        }
    });
```

Comment: have u checked to see that image is not null

Comment: if you do this operation in non-UI thread use need to implement runOnUiThread

Comment: I tried adding an imageview to my listview layout and if I set that image with the bitmap it works.

Comment: where you call this method setImage() , in  another thread where you download the image ??

Comment: yeah i sea it i ask are you about the image loader where you put it in the adapter also ??

Comment: No I put in my fragment I will update post.

Comment: But the images are working, but not in my adapter.

Comment: Was using another imageview class. Changed to ImageView and works better now ...